# Access values outside with-block

Tags: python, with-statement

Is there a way, in the code below, to access the variable `utterances_dict` outside of the `with`-block? The code below obviously returns the error: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

```
from csv import DictReader

utterances_dict = {}
utterance_file = 'toy_utterances.csv'

with open(utterance_file, 'r') as utt_f:
    utterances_dict = DictReader(utt_f)

for line in utterances_dict:
    print(line)
```

Comment: why do you want to use it outside ? Just put your for loop in the with strcture ?

Comment: I understand how to do it in this case. But the actual program is more multi-faceted

Comment: Wouldn't this work?: define a function, use with in that function and then return what you want, work with returned data

Comment: @Ruli - That could work; I'll play around with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on `DictReader` implementation, however [their documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) leaves the implementation open to the reader itself parsing the file after construction. Meaning it may be possible that the underlying file has to remain open until you are done using it. In this case, it would be problematic to attempt to use the `utterances_dict` outside of the `with` block because the underlying file will be closed by then.

Even if the current implementation of `DictReader` does in fact parse the whole csv on construction, it doesn't mean their implementation won't change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`DictReader` returns a view of the csv file.

Convert the result to a list of dictionaries.

```
from csv import DictReader

utterances = []
utterance_file = 'toy_utterances.csv'

with open(utterance_file, 'r') as utt_f:
    utterances = [dict(row) for row in DictReader(utt_f) ]

for line in utterances:
    print(line)
```